# Mac Rails install-- error: Error installing rails: invalid gem format for /Users/..../cache/railties-3.2.3.gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, installation

Using the Ruby on Rails tutorial for OSX here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial

It states to install the rails via "$ gem install rails -v 3.2.3", and when I do that I get the error

> Error installing rails:
>       invalid gem format for /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/cache/railties-3.2.3.gem

Comment: This isn't exactly fixing the problem, but to get around it I just did 

$ gem install rails -v 3.2.2

Note that's v 3.2.2 instead of 3.2.3.  Hopefully it doesn't effect me later in the tutorial 
:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your gem dependencies got messed up. Reinstall all your gems with this command:

```
gem pristine --all --no-extensions
```